# extract columns from TRUE/FALSE matrix based on proportion of TRUE values within the column

Tags: bash, text-processing, awk, grep

I have a text file like the one below although with almost many columns.
I want to extract column names that have a *specific proportion/number* of TRUE values, for example columns with TRUE in 2 out of the 9 rows (with TRUE/FALSE values).

Alternatively, it would be nice to extract columns *with at least* a certain number (e.g. 2) of TRUE values. In the example above, it would be columns with 2 to a possible 9 rows with TRUE values. Should be generalizable to files with different number of rows.

Thanks!

Example of input file:

```
Comparison  MT  group1  group1.1    group1.2    group1.3    group1.4    group1.5    group1.6    group1.7    group1.8    group1.9
BP:HA      FALSE FALSE  FALSE       FALSE       FALSE       FALSE       FALSE       FALSE       FALSE       FALSE        TRUE
CB:HA      FALSE TRUE   FALSE       FALSE       FALSE       FALSE       FALSE       FALSE       FALSE       FALSE        FALSE 
HA:PI      TRUE  TRUE   FALSE       FALSE       FALSE       FALSE       FALSE       FALSE       FALSE       FALSE        FALSE 
AL:GR      FALSE FALSE  FALSE       FALSE       FALSE       FALSE       FALSE       FALSE       FALSE       FALSE        FALSE 
AL:LA      TRUE  FALSE  FALSE       FALSE       FALSE       FALSE       FALSE       FALSE       FALSE       FALSE        FALSE 
AL:PL      FALSE FALSE  FALSE       FALSE       FALSE       FALSE       FALSE       FALSE       FALSE       TRUE         FALSE 
GR:PP      FALSE FALSE  FALSE       FALSE       FALSE       FALSE       FALSE       FALSE       FALSE       FALSE        FALSE 
LA:PP      TRUE  FALSE  FALSE       FALSE       FALSE       FALSE       FALSE       FALSE       FALSE       FALSE        TRUE
PL:PP      FALSE FALSE  FALSE       FALSE       FALSE       FALSE       FALSE       FALSE       FALSE       FALSE        TRUE
```

**Desired outcome for columns with 2 or more TRUE values**:

output file:

```
MT
group1
group1.9
```

Comment: Do you care about the column headers? They're all the same in your sample, how would you identify the columns from the output?

Comment: Please clarify if column headers matter and how you were planning to search for "columns with 5 to a possible 9 rows". Would the ideal be to search for a certain minimum percentage value?

I think R or Python would be better than both awk and grep for solving this.

Comment: post the expected result

Comment: I would like to get the column name in the output. Column names are different and they do matter, I've made the edits to my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scan all columns and accumulate the count of "TRUE" for each column.
At the end, print all columns that are equal or bigger than a set point:

```
#!/bin/bash
awk -vprop="${1:-0.3}" '
        NR==1{split($0,fields);next};
        {for(i=2;i<=NF;i++){  if($i=="TRUE" ){t[i]++};
                              if($i=="FALSE"){f[i]++}
                           }
        }
        END{
            for(j in t)
            if( (1/(1+f[j]/t[j])) >= prop){
                printf("%-10s\t%s\t%s\n",fields[j],j,1/(1+f[j]/t[j]) )
            }
        }' infile
```

On execution (for the data you supplied):

```
$ ./script  0.001
MT              i=2     t=3     f=6     p=0.333
group1          i=3     t=2     f=7     p=0.222
group1.8        i=11    t=1     f=8     p=0.111
group1.9        i=12    t=3     f=6     p=0.333
```

Column 2 (MT) has more than 1 TRUE values: 3 in fact.
Column 3 (group1) has 2 TRUE values.
Column 11 (group1.8) has 1 TRUE value. 
Column 12 (group1.9) has 3 TRUE values.

If you do not supply a proportion, it defaults to 0.3.

```
$ ./script
MT              i=2     t=3     f=6     p=0.333
group1          i=3     t=2     f=7     p=0.222
group1.9        i=12    t=3     f=6     p=0.333
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way of picking out the columns with enough instances of `TRUE`, using bash:

```
min_true=3; \
max_col=12; \
for col in $(seq 2 $max_col); do \
  sed 's,    ,.,g;s,   ,.,g' "$filename" | \
    tail -n+2 | \
    cut -d. -f$col > /tmp/f; \
  count=$(grep TRUE /tmp/f | wc -l); \
  if [ "$count" -ge "$min_true" ]; then \
    echo "Column $(($col-1)): $count out of $(echo $(wc -l </tmp/f))"; \
    cat /tmp/f; \
  fi; \
done
```

The output can be grepped for strings like "3 out of 9", to get the column number (counting from 0):

```
Column 1: 3 out of 9
FALSE
FALSE
TRUE
FALSE
TRUE
FALSE
FALSE
TRUE
FALSE
```

Comment: Thanks! is there a way to get the column heading/name for the the example?

Answer (score 0):

```
$ awk -v p='10' 'NR==1 { split($0,cols); next }
                 { 
                     for (i=2; i<=NF; ++i)
                         nt[i] += ($i == "TRUE" ? 1 : 0 )
                 }
                 END {
                     for (i=2; i<=NF; ++i) {
                         cp = 100*nt[i]/NR
                         if (cp > p) printf("%-20s %.2f%%\n", cols[i], cp)
                     }
                 }' file
MT                   30.00%
group1               20.00%
group1.9             30.00%
```

The `awk` program takes a parameter `p` which is the percentage of `TRUE` that is required for a column header to be displayed.

From the first line, it saves all the column headers into the array `cols`. It then sums up how many times the word `TRUE` occurs in each column.  At the end, it calculates the percentage of rows that were `TRUE` in each column as `cp` and compares this to `p`.  If it's greater than the given `p` value, the column name and the percentage is outputted.